# Communicating between parent and child iFrame windows with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've got a page which contains an iFrame and within the iFrame is a table whose rows I would like to attach a click event to.

Normally this would be easy, but I need to retrieve the selected table row within the iFrame from the parent window and this is throwing me for a loop.

The basic idea is that when a user clicks on a table row, a class is added to row using something like this (pseudo-code, there is functionality that removes any existing instances of the class so it is unique):

```
$('#table tr').on('click', function() {
   .addClass('.selectedRow');
});
```

Then in the parent window I figure I can do something like this:

```
$('#desktopIframe').contents().find('.selectedRow');
```

But I'm not sure what to attach this to so that as soon as there is a table row with the 'selectedRow' class I can identify it and do some other stuff with it. Normally I'd use .on('click') but what do I attach this to?

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like this

```
$('#desktopIframe').contents().find('#table tr').on("click", function() {
   $(this).addClass(".selectedRow");
});
```

*(Please note that this is untested)*

Comment: Thanks for the response but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can't see anything popping up in the console, simply nothing is happening

Comment: Is your `<iframe>` from the same domain??

Comment: Yes it is. Lengthening message for 15 char limit

Comment: try loggin `$('#desktopIframe').contents().find('#table tr')` this in the console and see if you get anything

Comment: Yes, I get an object returned if I do that

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem which actually involved reversing the logic I was going for. Instead of getting the parent window to read the child window, I made the child window pass the data to the parent window instead.

So inside the iFrame I used a regular .on('click') event then just used this code to pass some data from the selected row to a field in the parent window which I can then manipulate:

parent.document.getElementById('hiddenField').value = $(this).blah();